# split document by using MarkLogic Flow Editor

Tags: xquery, marklogic

i try to split my incoming documents using "Information Studio Flows" (MarkLogic v 8.0-1.1). The problem is in "Transform" section.

This is my importing documents. For simplicity i reduce it content to one stwtext-element

```html
<docs>
 <stwtext id="RD-10-00258" update="03.2011" seq="RQ-10-00001">
  <head>
   <ti>
    <i>j</i>
   </ti>
   <ff-list>
    <ff id="0103"/>
   </ff-list>
  </head><p>
   Symbol für die
   <vw idref="RD-19-04447">Stromdichte</vw>
   .
  </p>
 </stwtext>
</docs>
```

This is my "xquery transform" content:

```html
xquery version "1.0-ml";

(: Copyright 2002-2015 MarkLogic Corporation.  All Rights Reserved. :)

(:
:: Custom action.  It must be a CPF action module.
:: Replace this text completely, or use it as a template and 
:: add imports, declarations,
:: and code between START and END comment tags.
:: Uses the external variables:
::    $cpf:document-uri: The document being processed
::    $cpf:transition: The transition being executed
:)

import module namespace cpf = "http://marklogic.com/cpf"
   at "/MarkLogic/cpf/cpf.xqy";

(: START custom imports and declarations; imports must be in Modules/ on filesystem :)


(: END custom imports and declarations :)

declare option xdmp:mapping "false";

declare variable $cpf:document-uri as xs:string external;
declare variable $cpf:transition as node() external;

if ( cpf:check-transition($cpf:document-uri,$cpf:transition))
then
    try {
       (: START your custom XQuery here :)
        

       let $doc := fn:doc($cpf:document-uri)
    return 
    xdmp:eval(
              for $wpt in fn:doc($doc)//stwtext
                return 
                  xdmp:document-insert(
                  fn:concat("/rom-data/", fn:concat($wpt/@id,".xml")),
                  $wpt
                  )
            )



       (: END your custom XQuery here :)
       ,
       cpf:success( $cpf:document-uri, $cpf:transition, () )
    }
    catch ($e) {
       cpf:failure( $cpf:document-uri, $cpf:transition, $e, () )
    }
else ()
```

by running of snippet, i take the error:

```
Invalid URI format
```

and long description of it:

```html
 XDMP-URI: (err:FODC0005) fn:doc(fn:doc("/8122584828241226495/12835482492021535301/URI=/content/home/admin/Vorlagen/testing/v10.new-ML.xml")) -- Invalid URI format: "&#10;&#9;&#10;&#9; &#10;&#9;&#9;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;j&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;Symbol f&#252;r die&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;Stromdichte&#9;&#9;&#9;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#10;&#9;&#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;"
In /18200382103958065126.xqy on line 37
In xdmp:invoke("/18200382103958065126.xqy", (xs:QName("trgr:uri"), "/8122584828241226495/12835482492021535301/URI=/content/home/admi...", xs:QName("trgr:trigger"), ...), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><isolation>different-transaction</isolation><prevent-deadlocks>t...</options>)

$doc = fn:doc("/8122584828241226495/12835482492021535301/URI=/content/home/admin/Vorlagen/testing/v10.new-ML.xml")

In /MarkLogic/cpf/triggers/internal-cpf.xqy on line 179
In execute-action("on-state-enter", "http://marklogic.com/states/initial", "/8122584828241226495/12835482492021535301/URI=/content/home/admi...", (xs:QName("trgr:uri"), "/8122584828241226495/12835482492021535301/URI=/content/home/admi...", xs:QName("trgr:trigger"), ...), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><isolation>different-transaction</isolation><prevent-deadlocks>t...</options>, (fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/14379829270688061297.xml")/p:pipeline, fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/15861601524191348323.xml")/p:pipeline), fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/15861601524191348323.xml")/p:pipeline/p:state-transition[1]/p:default-action, fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/15861601524191348323.xml")/p:pipeline/p:state-transition[1])

$caller = "on-state-enter"
$state-or-status = "http://marklogic.com/states/initial"
$uri = "/8122584828241226495/12835482492021535301/URI=/content/home/admi..."
$vars = (xs:QName("trgr:uri"), "/8122584828241226495/12835482492021535301/URI=/content/home/admi...", xs:QName("trgr:trigger"), ...)
$invoke-options = <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><isolation>different-transaction</isolation><prevent-deadlocks>t...</options>
$pipelines = (fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/14379829270688061297.xml")/p:pipeline, fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/15861601524191348323.xml")/p:pipeline)
$action-to-execute = fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/15861601524191348323.xml")/p:pipeline/p:state-transition[1]/p:default-action
$chosen-transition = fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines/15861601524191348323.xml")/p:pipeline/p:state-transition[1]
$raw-module-name = "/18200382103958065126.xqy"
$module-kind = "xquery"
$module-name = "/18200382103958065126.xqy"

In /MarkLogic/cpf/triggers/internal-cpf.xqy on line 320
```

i thought, it was a problem with "Document setting" in "load" section of "Flow editor"

```
URI=/content{$path}/{$filename}{$dot-ext}
```

but if i remove it, i recive the same error.

i have no idea what to do. i am really new. please help

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Information Studio has been deprecated in MarkLogic 8. I would also recommend very much looking in to the aggregate_record feature of MarkLogic Content Pump:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/content-pump#id_65814

Apart from that, there are several issues with your code. You are calling fn:doc twice, effectively trying to interpret the doc contents as a uri. There is an unnecessary xdmp:eval wrapping the FLWOR statement, which expects a string as first param. I think you can shorten it to (showing inner part of the action only):

```
   (: START your custom XQuery here :)

   let $doc := fn:doc($cpf:document-uri)
   for $wpt in $doc//stwtext
   return
     xdmp:document-insert(
       fn:concat("/roempp-data/", fn:concat($wpt/@id,".xml")),
       $wpt
     )

   (: END your custom XQuery here :)
```

HTH!

Comment: thank you very much! 
I would like to inform you now about this bug in my code too. And i made other approach

Comment: To your remark about deprecated of "Information studio", it is new for me, but ok. But before i try to do my issue with  "Information Studio", i did try to do it with mlcp. I am not sure, but perhaps there is bug in mlcp for my issue. I will post about it in other "Ask"

Comment: so, this is the issue to split with mlcp
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120344/split-document-by-using-marklogic-mlcp

Answer (score 0):

very many thanks @grtjn and this is my approach. Practically it is the same solution

```html
           (: START your custom XQuery here :)
            
           xdmp:log(fn:doc($cpf:document-uri), "debug"),
           let $doc := fn:doc($cpf:document-uri)                 

        return 
xdmp:eval('
          declare variable $doc external;
          for $wpt in $doc//stwtext
           return (
                      xdmp:document-insert(
                      fn:concat("/roempp-data/", fn:concat($wpt/@id,".xml")),
                      $wpt,
                      xdmp:default-permissions(),
                      "roempp-data"
                      )
          )'
        ,
(xs:QName("doc"), $doc),
            <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
                <database>{xdmp:database("roempp-tutorial")}</database>
            </options>

)
    
           (: END your custom XQuery here :)
```

Ok, now it works. It is fine, but i found, that after the loading is over, i see in MarkLogic two documents:

1. my splited document "/rom-data/RD-10-00258.xml" with one root element "stwtext" (as desired)
2. **origin** document "URI=/content/home/admin/Vorlagen/testing/v10.new-ML.xml" with root element "docs"

is it possible to prohibit insert of **origin** document ?

Comment: You cannot prohibit insert of original document, as the insert itself activates this action. I think you can delete it though.